# How can I deal with getActivity()?

Tags: java, android

```
 import com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter;

private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
@Override
public void call(final Object... args) {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
            String username;
            String message;
            try {
                username = data.getString("username");
                message = data.getString("message");
            } catch (JSONExpextion e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}
};
```

When I put in this code in my project, it said "Cannot resolve method 
    get Activity "
then, how can I deal with this problem?

Comment: Try to use `this` instead of `getActivity()`or the name of your activity.
And where do you call this `method` into an activity or somewhere else ?

Comment: No, but I don't know where I add the method...

Comment: @Spritzig Using only `this` won't help as the method is called from inner class.

Comment: @Gourav I gave two options `this` or the name of the `Activity` which you have added at your answer :)

Comment: I just pointed out for `this`. Never mind!

Comment: Pass the data back in activity with the help of interface and then use context for runOnUiThread

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getActivity()` from inner class `Emitter`. So you should replace `getActivity()` with the name of your activity followed by `.this`. For example the name of your activity is MainActivity, then replace `getActivity()` with `MainActivity.this`

And your code would be like this:

```
private Emitter.Listener onNewMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
@Override
public void call(final Object... args) {
    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
            String username;
            String message;
            try {
                username = data.getString("username");
                message = data.getString("message");
            } catch (JSONExpextion e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
}
};
```